# How to get location in DMS on Flutter/Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, geolocation, location, geolocator

so I use geolocator to get the place location, but it gives a decimal. But my app need the location as degrees, minutes and seconds, is there another package/lib that can do it, our a way to do that with geolocator,      tried formatting with sub string but to no avail (maybe I did it wrong).

Comment: You just have to convert Decimal to sixtieth

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.